# Android show float button when focus on every application textbox

Tags: android

I want to show float button or box when user click on textbox and textbox focused.
For example, in sms app user click on textbox to type something and app show float button to user. How can i implement this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You can use setOnFocusChangeListener() on your text box.